# The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-webapi

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeQDZ.png)

Hello everyone, I get this error message after clicking File->new->project->web->click here to go online and find templates->choosing ASP.net core/Angular 8 Project template.
I use Microsoft visual studio 2015 .net version is 3.1.100. Does anyone know a fix to this problem or what is causing it? I'm new to .net and this my first project. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .net version is 3.1.100

There is no .NET Framework 3.1.x (there was 3.0 and then 3.5).

It seems you are trying to load a .NET ***Core*** 3.1 project in Visual Studio 2015.

But .NET Core 3.1 is *only* supported in Visual Studio 2019 (16.3 and later, easier sub-versions only support Core 3.0).